# saddle point property in optimal control

Tags: convex-optimization, optimal-control

I'm currently reading a paper on optimal control, where a the dual of a control problem is derived. Two properties of the primal and the dual problem are proven, first strong duality, which I understand the use of, and then a saddle point property.

The concept of a saddle point in optimal control confuses me, does anyone have insight?

Thanks!

Comment: The saddle point has to do with the duality, it  is not specific to optimal conyrol

Comment: Could you please add the reference to the paper you are reading?

Answer (score 1):

In case if you are talking about hyperbolic saddle point well then its a point where the Unstable manifold and stable manifold intersect and in such cases if you are going to control such a system well then you required to have controllers such as LQG,Nonlinear controllers or Adaptive controllers-The use of controllers depend upon the type of system & what do you want to achieve(economical feasibility,accuracy & other factors) 
.For more details please refer to, page number 102 of this book https://www.springer.com/in/book/9781461381617